# HTTP Status 403 error from glassfish 3 when trying to reach an implemented login page

Tags: glassfish-3

I have created a login page using a nice guide that I found about Java EE6 and GlassFish3 using netbeans.
After deploying the project when I try to reach the login page I get 'HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied' from GlassFish3 server.

The url I am using is : http://localhost:9999/simplewebapp/admin/admin.jsp
The guide says that I should automatically be redirected to the login page I have created.

Instead I am receiving the above error.
Looking at the glassfish3 log I am getting these two lines when I am entering the above url.

INFO: JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context (" simplewebapp/simplewebapp ") , permission (" (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /admin/login.jsp GET) ") 
INFO: JACC Policy Provider:Failed Permission Check: context (" simplewebapp/simplewebapp ") , permission (" (javax.security.jacc.WebUserDataPermission /admin/login.jsp GET:CONFIDENTIAL) ")

Some more details :

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administrative Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>admin</description>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrators</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Users</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>appadmin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Does it try to find login.jsp inside admin folder?

Comment: My login.jsp file is at the root directory of the application just like the book code I have downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.I had to add principal names in glassfish-web.xml and a role-name in web.xml.
Correct files :

web-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administrative Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description>admin</description>
            <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrators</description>
        <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>Users</description>
        <role-name>UserRole</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>AdminRole</role-name>
    <principal-name>admin</principal-name>
    <group-name>appadmin</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>UserRole</role-name>
    <principal-name>user</principal-name>
    <group-name>appuser</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Also note the glassfish bug: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-19064. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268255

Answer (score 0):

Using glassfish Admin Console this worked for me:

Select ‘server-config’ listed under Configurations and access the Security page. On that page 
you need to enable the ‘Default Principal to Role Mapping’ option. The benefit of enabling this option is that it enables us to use roles defined for users shortly automatically without 
requiring us to make formal XML declarations in a glassfish configuration file for our project.

Answer (score 0):

For keeping it "standard" I think this is the better option, because if you're using just a web container (eg. tomcat), you're not gonna have to configure nothing else that just a realm. In my case, I was using Eclipse and had to undeploy the project and redeploy it.

Thank you very much.